# Call a Gen-2 GCP Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I have deployed the following 2 functions on GCP Cloud Function: gcloud functions list

#1

```
NAME: myfunction-no-01
STATE: ACTIVE
TRIGGER: HTTP Trigger
REGION: us-central1
ENVIRONMENT: 1st gen
```

#2

```
NAME: myfunction-no-01-gen2
STATE: ACTIVE
TRIGGER: HTTP Trigger
REGION: us-central1
ENVIRONMENT: 2nd gen
```

I tried to call both functions from the CLI on the browser, but the gen-2 function (#2) doesn't work.

#1

```
webmaster@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$ gcloud functions describe myfunction-no-01
availableMemoryMb: 512
buildId: 46c6f552-4987-4998-ac3c-48d62aefe1b
buildName: projects/411817252346/locations/us-central1/builds/46c6f552-4987-4998-ac3c-48d62aefe1b
dockerRegistry: CONTAINER_REGISTRY
entryPoint: entrypoint
environmentVariables:
  GDRIVE_CONFIG_YML_FILE_ID: 1WflpktOjJ9zPquHVO45rxuUNo-lBsjr
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_ALWAYS
  url: https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction-no-01
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: console-cloud
maxInstances: 3000
name: projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/myfunction-no-01
runtime: python39
serviceAccountEmail: my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-204034571949.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/874e8ab6-9bac-477e-8430-a8ebbe9262fa.zip
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 540s
updateTime: '2022-10-24T22:20:53.884Z'
versionId: '4'
```

#2

```
webmaster@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$ gcloud functions describe myfunction-no-01-gen2
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.describe) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function myfunction-no-01-gen2 in region us-central1 in project my-project does not exist]
webmaster@cloudshell:~ (my-project)$
```

Could anyone please enlighten:

- How does one call a gen-2 function?
- Can I call a gen-2 function from the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `--gen2` while calling gen2 functions. The command should be like below

```
gcloud functions describe myfunction-no-01-gen2 --region=us-cental1 --gen2
```

Have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/describe#:%7E:text=FLAGS-,%2D%2Dgen2,-If%20enabled%2C%20this:%7E:text=functions/region.-,FLAGS,-%2D%2Dgen2)

And make sure gen2 function is exists in specified region